# How can I redirect (301) with htaccess URL with percent?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a lot of URLs that I have to redirect. examples:

/index.php?act=viewtag&tag=%EB%F8%E9%F1_%E0%E5%E5%F0%F1 >> To >> another URL

/index.php?act=viewtag&tag=%F9%F8%E4_%EE%E9%F9%EC_%E2%EC%F8 >> To >> another URL

each redirect should be to another URL. I mean the destination of the first exmaple and the second exmaple is not the same page.. and theres alot of redirect to do with a lot of different URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=viewtag&tag=%EB%F8%E9%F1_%E0%E5%E5%F0%F1$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /another-url? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=viewtag&tag=%F9%F8%E4_%EE%E9%F9%EC_%E2%EC%F8$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /another-url? [L,R]
```

Comment: Your code make this URL: domain.com/index.php?act=viewtag&tag=%EB%F8%E9%F1_%E0%E5%E5%F0%F1

 to: 

newdomain.com/index.php?act=viewtag&tag=%EB%F8%E9%F1_%E0%E5%E5%F0%F1
.
 I want it to redirect to the URL I WRITE.
 I mean to

 newdomain.com
 or
 newdomain.com/page

Comment: @user3332898 sorry, forgot a ? at the end